# .net application running at network share folder

Tags: .net, networking

We have a complicated application installed on the server machine. It is run on the client machine by creating a shortcut to the exe at the shared folder of the server machine. The exe and dlls are not in the same folder. 
Running this application from the server machine is fine. 
However, when running the application from the client machine, dlls called by Assembly.LoadFile or the serializable class Deserialize will raise an error.

```
calling dlls error: this file or its dependences are not found
Deserialize error: System.InvalidOperationException
```

We don't have this issue on .NET 2.0. It appears after upgrading to .NET 4.0.

Comment: It seems that some DLLs are missing under you application folder...

Comment: Did you upgrade your client and server machine to .net 4.0?

Comment: Dlls are there. running from the server machine is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you upgraded server machine to 4.0, but not client machine? Then when application tries to load some System .dlls it fails to find them on client.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Let me double check if the client has 4.0 installation. My question: the dlls are in the server, why the client is looking for them on client? Thanks.

Comment: Your .dlls are on server, but machine running this program must have system .dlls on running machine because not all .dlls are deployed with application. To run .NET application you must have whole .NET ( in your case 4.0) environment installed on machine which is running the application.

Comment: The client has 4.0 installation also.

Comment: Do you have c++ code in your .dlls? If yes, than you should install latest redistributables. You will find solution in EventViewer, open your program, and than check details about which .dll was not loaded. If you paste .dll name here than I can help more.

Comment: No, we don't have c++ code. All the code is in c#. The dlls are not system dlls, they are dlls (domain).

Comment: Which .dll is missing, check EventViewer